# P/invoke DLL functions from C++ dll in C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, pinvoke

I have a problem with invoking a few functions from DLL (SDK of some camera). In source of .dll, there is function:

```
NET_SDK_API LONG CALL_METHOD NET_SDK_Login(char *sDVRIP,WORD wDVRPort,char *sUserName,char *sPassword,LPNET_SDK_DEVICEINFO lpDeviceInfo);
```

and I am trying to call it from .Net console app with following code:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long userid = 0;

    _net_sdk_deviceinfo dinfo = new _net_sdk_deviceinfo();
    short port = 6036;

    try
    {

        if (DVR.NET_SDK_Init())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ok");
            userid = DVR.NET_SDK_Login("192.168.1.132", port, "admin", "123456", out dinfo);
            userid.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("err");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

i get following error:

> A call to PInvoke function 'DVRtest!DVRtest.DVR::NET_SDK_Login' has
>   unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that
>   the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match
>   the target unmanaged signature.

Init passes fine but i cant get anything else. I tried dozen of solutions and I'm getting nowhere.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/bKTJxZ47) is source of dll and [source](http://pastebin.com/d0DiYwsG) of my .Net app. Thanks!

[edit]

As @david pointed out, CallingConvention was wrong and now, i get following error:

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x6fda02c7, on thread 0x2554. The error code is 0xc0000005.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

Is this error from DLL or CLR (.Net)? I never imported any functions from DLL to .Net, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the unmanaged source:

```
#define CALL_METHOD __stdcall
```

And from the managed source:

```
[DllImport("DVR_NET_SDK.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Your calling conventions do not match.

---

As for the edit to the question, that is presumably because the C# struct definition does not match the unmanaged struct. You have failed to translate any of the arrays correctly. They will require the use of `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=...)]`.

Comment: Still no luck....

`The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x6fda02c7, on thread 0x2e44. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.`

Comment: That's a different bug. I'm not keen on debugging your entire program. However, I can tell you that your C# struct translation is wrong. You've failed to translate any of the arrays correctly. You are going to need `UnmanagedType.ByValArray`. Do please bear in mind that your question does not include the code, and asks very specifically about the stack imbalance error.

Comment: I think I've answered both of the questions that you have asked. Strictly speaking we like to have one question at a time here.